# How do I get my CPU off the MoBo if the paste is gluey?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a Phenom II 965 Black Edition. Those come with Fans with Thermal paste pre-applied.
So I always just put it on without thinking much about it.

However, when I bought it, it was a fast shot because my old PC died. So I bought a really cheap MoBo which I am not happy with right now. I want to buy a new MoBo that supports my current CPU as well as FX CPU's.

When I wanted to change my dual core that I had on this board before I bought my current Quadcore, I ripped the whole CPU out while the handle was still down. I got lucky and no Pins where bended or even ripped off, which would have ruined the whole motherboard. Reason is, that the Thermal Paste kinda melts the CPU and the Heatsink together. This type of problem is something you can read all over the Internet.

If I exchange the MoBo, I need to get the CPU out in a way that does not damage it and put it on the new MoBo. But, I also need to get the Heatsink off.

What can I do in this case to first get the Fan off my CPU without damaging anything if it is that tight again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quality thermal paste should not significantly attach a CPU to a heat sink. It should separate fairly easily, even after eight years or more. If excessive force is necessary, you have four options, from best to worst:

1. If the CPU is the type where the CPU itself is physically held by the socket (such as most modern Intel CPUs), twist the heat sink until the thermal compound "cracks".
2. Unlatch the CPU from the motherboard and lift the CPU out by the heat sink. Flip the heat sink over and gently twist the CPU off the heat sink.
3. With a thin, stiff plastic object (such as a credit card), try to separate the CPU from the heat sink by pressing them apart.
4. With a small, flathead screwdriver, gently pry the heat sink apart from the CPU. Try not to scratch the CPU's mating surface.

Comment: With AMD Boards you only have this little handle that shifts a platform inside the socket. The CPU is basically held by the fan.

Comment: Good stuff, also depending on why it wont free, if you take the pressure off the mounting, then wait some time before trying to releace it, it could help.  (suction of an active tim and perfect mating , not going to help dried up stuff)